# How can I prevent lag when recording video on HTC Desire S?

Tags: video-recording

I have lags after recording and playing back videos on my HTC device. Look at this video capture:

**˃** http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qmOAr476DHc&hd=1

I thought it had something to do with autofocus but it is only available in shoot mode. Maybe it is still active in video capturing mode but without ability to let user change settings so they can only be changed in shooting mode? This happened with stock Sandisk 8GB Class 4 SD card and happens with Sandisk 16GB Class 4 SD card that i bought recently.

*HTC Desire S*
*Android 2.3.3 (stock)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable USB debugging, plug your phone into a computer via USB for a couple of minutes and disconnect. - [source](http://www.stefanoforenza.com/how-to-fix-htc-desire-hd-lag/)

You can also try a faster memory card, as ^ has adviced.

Keep some reasonable amount of free space on phone memory, move apps to SD card if necessary. Android often suffers performance issues when internal memory is low (much like any OS, really).

If nothing else works, try a factory reset and record it again. If there are no lags, it might be because of any resource-intensive apps you have installed.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried using Kingston Class 4? If you can find Class 10, even better!

[Source](http://www.htcdesirehdforum.com/htc-desire-hd-troubleshooting/htc-desire-hd-which-microsd-cards-for-hd-video/)